# Vue instance in double quotes

Tags: vue.js, metro-ui-css

I use vue instance but it is not parsing , i think problem is relevant with using double quotes in **Metro.dialog.Create.content**.

Here is the main page include table and it works correctly.I added when dblclick table on main page open dialog and another table showing in this dialog.

```
var app2= new Vue({
      el: '#appTable',
      data: {
          squads: [                
          ]
      },        
      mounted: function () {
          Metro.init();
          var self = this;
           $.ajax({
               url: '@Url.Action("Find", "Squad")',
               method: 'GET',
               success: function (data) {
                   self.squads = data;
               },                  
           });
      },
      methods:{
        clickList: function (squad) {
            bindSquadToEditTable(squad.ID);
            Metro.dialog.create({
                title: "Team",
                content:
                  '<div class ="row-4-3 rowspan" >'+
                     '<div id="appTableMembers">'+
                       '<table class="table cell-border ">'+
                         '<thead>'+
                            '<tr>'+
                            '<th>Personal Code</th>'+
                             '<th>Name</th>'+
                              '<th>Email</th>'+
                               '</tr>'+
                          '</thead>'+
                       '<tbody>'+
                       "<tr v-for=squad in members :key=squad.PersonalCode >  <td>{{squad.PersonalCode}}</td>  <td>{{squad.FullName}}</td> <td>{{squad.Email}}</td>"+
                        '</tr>'+
                        '</tbody>'+
                  '</table>'+
                 '</div>',
            });
        }
      }
  });
```

That is my Main page;

```
        <div id="appTable">
    <table class="table striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="squad in squads" :key="squad.Code" v-on:dblclick="clickList(squad)">
                <td>{{squad.Code}}</td> <td>{{squad.Description}}</td> 
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Here is the binding data to dialog ;

```
   <script>
         function bindSquadToEditTable(ID){
              app3 = new Vue({
                  el: 'appTableMembers',
                  data: {
                      members:[]
                  },
                  mounted:function(){
                      Metro.init();
                      var self = this;
                      $.ajax({
                          type: "GET",
                          "url": '@Url.Action("FindByID", "Squad")',
                  "data": { id: ID },
                  "dataSrc": "",
                  success: function(data){
                      self.members = data;
                  },
              });
          }
       })
     }
  </script>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what "is not parsing" means?  Are you getting an error somewhere?  If so, what's the error and where does it occur?  Also, in the second paragraph you state "and it works correctly" so it's not clear exactly what your question is.

Comment: I have 2 table. first table in main page and second table in the  dialog.First Table works correctly and when dblclick this table open dialog and showing second table.But showing second table rows like that {{squad.PersonalCode}} so i write parsing problem.Also , i am not getting any error.

Comment: My guess is that Vue controls the DOM, but you're giving your dialog string-based HTML -- not from the DOM so Vue has no control over it.  Is there any way you could put the dialog's HTML in a hidden div?  This would let Vue manage it, but you could point your dialog to that DOM node instead of raw HTML.

Comment: Yes, i thought that  guess too and i will  apply it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was curious how this would work so I threw together a [quick test](https://jsfiddle.net/psteele/apuca8jo/).  Worked fine using the hidden `<div>` for the modal content.

#### HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.metroui.org.ua/v4/css/metro-all.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <input type="button" value="modal" @click="showModal" />
      <div style="display: none" ref="modalContent">
        <div>My name is {{name}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.metroui.org.ua/v4/js/metro.min.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

### Javascript

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
        name: 'Sample User'
    },
  methods: {
    showModal: function() {
      Metro.dialog.create({
          title: "Modal Title",
          content: this.getModalContent
          });
    },
    getModalContent: function() {
        return this.$refs.modalContent.innerHTML;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, for your approach.I implemented little differ.Should I add my solution here ?

Comment: @JohnConnor Sure, add it as an additional answer.  It's always good to have options!  :)

Answer (score 0):

I change the my opinion and i will implement modal in the script;

```
<script type="text/template" id="data-input-form-template" >
            <label>Code</label>
            <input type="text" v-model="squad[0].Code"/> 

            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" v-model="squad[0].Name" />


            <label>Description</label>
            <textarea style="height:175px" v-model="squad[0].Description"></textarea>

        <div id="appTableMembers">
            <table class="cell-border" >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Personal Code</th>
                        <th>Adı</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="m in squad[0].members">
                        <td>{{m.PersonalCode}}</td>
                        <td>{{m.FullName}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
</script>
```

And this my openDialog function;

```
function openDialog(ID) {       
     var html = $('#data-input-form-template').html();
     $('#data-input-form').html(html);
     app4 =  new Vue({
         el:'#data-input-form',
         data: function(){
             return {
                 squad: [{
                     members: []
                 }]
             }
         },
         mounted:function(){
             Metro.init();
             var self = this;
                 $.ajax({
                     type: "GET",
                     "url": '@Url.Action("FindByID", "Squad")',
                     "data": { id: ID },
                     "dataSrc": "",
                     success: function (data) {
                         self.squad = data;
                     },
                     error: function (error) {
                         alert(error);
                     }
                 });  
         }
     });
    Metro.dialog.open('#demoDialog1');       
}
```

Main Page html;

```
    <div class="dialog" data-role="dialog"  id="demoDialog1"> src="#" />
    <div class="dialog-content" style="height:400px">
        <form id="data-input-form">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```